# what is the difference between the terms CMS and Script?

Tags: content-management-system

What is the difference website CMS and website script?

WordPress, Joomla, Drupal = CMS.

Xenforo, Opencart, whmcs and etc = script or cms?

For example, only scripts are sold on a codecanyon (forum script, shop script and etc)

Answer (score 0):

A content management system in this context is a web software application for managing the creation and modification of digital content, the content of which is typically article based.  Wordpress is primarily used as a blog CMS centered around articles and is very easy for beginners.  Joomla and Drupal are for more advanced users and has more capabilities for building larger more advanced systems.

Xenforo is forum software, it doesn't have article support out of the box but is a thread and post based web software.  It has many features, it's hard to call it a CMS because it is not article based. It's purpose is for community based discussion.

A script is a file that is parsed and executed by an interpreter, by itself a script doesn't do anything by itself.  These web softwares are collections of scripts but I would not call them a script themselves.

Code Canyon sells addons, plugins & themes which extend prebuilt CMS and other web software but again I wouldn't call most of these scripts.

Answer (score 0):

A content management system, usually abbreviated as "CMS", is basically just a piece of software that you install on your web host's computer. That is, instead of installing the program on your own computer, the way you do a web editor, you install it directly on your website. You then use your browser to log into your website and use it to add articles, photos, or whatever to your website.

In one sense, using a CMS has some superficial similarities to using your web host's online site builder, which is probably why the visitor asking me this question was confused. For example, when you use a CMS, you don't need to install any program on your own computer to create and update your website. You just connect to your site with your browser and modify it directly.

On the other hand, CMSes also have their own disadvantages over a web host's site builder. For example, they rarely have the huge range of web design templates that an online site builder has. ("Templates", in this context, are just pre-made web designs that you can use wholesale, or customise, for your site.) However, if you use a CMS platform that is very popular, you can probably find some free template somewhere on the Internet, possibly even directly on the CMS author's own website, that you can adapt. CMSes are also much harder to set up. You have to learn how to do things like transfer files from your computer to your web host's computer, set up a database, and configure the CMS for your site. Once you're through with the initial stages, however, it's probably easier, since you have much greater control over the CMS than an online site builder (since the latter is controlled by your web host). Many popular CMS programs even have add-on modules that extend the functionality of the CMS, so even if the basic CMS package doesn't have everything you want, you can often install one or more of these modules to provide the missing feature.

A script is a file that is parsed and executed by an interpreter, by itself a script doesn't do anything by itself. These web softwares are collections of scripts but I would not call them a script themselves.